# Deleting a row based on the max value

Tags: mysql, sql, max, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

How can I structure a mySQL query to delete a row based on the max value.

I tried

```
WHERE jobPositonId = max(jobPostionId)
```

but got an error?

Comment: I would advise against that. How come you don't know a certain id of the row to be deleted?

Comment: @Common Sense, as the question states, the desired row to be deleted is the row which is defined by a max value (rather than a row defined by an id).   This would accomplish in one query what you might propose to do in two? That is, query for the id of the max row; then delete that row.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE t1 
       JOIN (SELECT MAX(jobPositonId) AS max_id FROM TABLE) t2 
 WHERE t1.jobPositonId  = t2.max_id
```

Mind that ***all*** the rows with that `jobPositonId` value will be removed, if there are duplicates.

The stupid part about the 1093 error is that you can get around it by placing a subquery between the self reference:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
 WHERE jobPositonId = (SELECT x.id
                         FROM (SELECT MAX(t.jobPostionId) AS id 
                                 FROM TABLE t) x)
```

### Explanation

MySQL is only checking, when using `UPDATE` & `DELETE` statements, if the there's a first level subquery to the same table that is being updated.  That's why putting it in a second level (or deeper) subquery alternative works.  But it's only checking subqueries - the JOIN syntax is logically equivalent, but doesn't trigger the error.

Comment: @Robert de Klerk: See update to my answer to explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 21):

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY jobPositonId DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perfect! Deleted all rows at once in my self-referencing table. (without the limit 1 of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE jobPositonId = (select max(jobPostionId) from `table_name` limit 1)
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE jobPositonId IN (select max(jobPostionId) from `table_name` limit 1)
```

Comment: MySQL error 1093 - can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Comment: Why would you even need the LIMIT clause if you are using Max with no correlation or group by?

Comment: Same error
    MySQL error 1093 - can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Comment: Sorry for my bad info, I didn't have time to test it, +1 for Konerak, he post the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT @lastid := max(jobPositonId ) from t1; 
DELETE from t1 WHERE jobPositonId = @lastid ;
```

Other than going to the database twice, is there anything wrong with this technique?