# MySQL UPDATE - Selective update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1054

First up, apologies for the awful title I couldn't think of a better way to articulate my issue. (Feel free to suggest better altnernatives)

Basically I have a table with a "count" column.
I want to reset all counts to zero except for the 10 rows with the top values.  I want them to be reset to 0.

How do I achieve this without writing multiple queries?

**Update**
I have my query as the following now

```
UPDATE covers AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.cover_id 
               FROM covers t 
               ORDER BY t.cover_views DESC 
               LIMIT 10) AS t2 ON t2.id = t.id
   SET cover_views = 0
   WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

I get the error `#1054 - Unknown column 't2.id' in 'where clause'` - any idea why?

I also tried the following with the same result

```
UPDATE covers t1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.cover_id 
               FROM covers t 
               ORDER BY t.cover_views DESC 
               LIMIT 10) t2 ON t2.id = t.id
   SET t1.cover_views = 0
   WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there an id column or Primary Key column?

Comment: @Chris...looks like @Wadhi answered it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
update <table> t 
left outer join 
(
select id from <table> order by <counter> desc limit 10
) c on c.id = t.id 
set 
 <counter> = 0
where 
 c.id is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
UPDATE TABLE t1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.id 
               FROM TABLE t 
           ORDER BY t.id DESC 
              LIMIT 10) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
   SET TABLE.count = 0
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks this looks perfect, anyway I can set all from the joined table to be 1 in the same query or do I have to do another?

Comment: I ran into a small problem implementing your query - I updated question - could you please take a look?

Comment: watch out for the order by t.id desc limit 10 - you did say "I want to reset all counts to zero except for the 10 rows with the top values" so maybe that should be order by <counter_field> desc limit 10

Comment: @chris: It was because of a typo in the JOIN - `LIMIT 10) t2 ON t2.id = t.id` was supposed to be: `LIMIT 10) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id`.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: Ah cheers, I marked your answer up but already accepted f00's 'cos it worked first.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
update A set count = 0 where A.id not in 
(select id from A order by count desc limit 10)
```

Comment: MySQL error 1093 - can't specify target table for update in FROM clause. For more info, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620940/deleting-a-row-based-on-the-max-value/3621005#3621005

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks OMG Ponies. How would you correct the code?

Comment: If you put a subquery between the UPDATE and the subquery returning data, MySQL will accept it - there's an example in the link I provided.